# Allow multiple chat rooms in the same browser window

Tags: feature-request, chat

### Problem

Having multiple tabs open, or using the "other rooms you're in" feature, are both slightly cumbersome ways to see what's going on in different chat rooms.

### Solution

Possible solution :) Allow multiple chats to display on the screen at once. Mockup, to illustrate the point. Zoom the page to view more detail:

[image]

Commentary:

1. The pin icon at the top would be how users would remove the chat room if they didn't want it in this view any more
2. The thing could potentially scale based on the number of rooms (e.g. for only 2, it would be 50%/50%)
3. The top info could expand down over the chat to show all the information that was cut off with ellipses on hover (e.g. the JavaScript room has too much info in the tags, people, description and star sections to show, so these could be expanded in the hovered version).
4. I haven't shown how to add a new room. Possibly (say) if the user had just one room open, 100% width, they could select somewhere how many rooms they wanted open, and the view would change to be divided into thirds, and in each of the two empty ones they could pick the room they wanted.
5. I've just shown the URL for the first room. In reality it'd probably be better to have a bookmarkable URL that shows all the rooms.
6. I guess you'd need a way to highlight which room your cursor is sat in, to avoid typing messages to the wrong room.

### Thanks for watching

Hope it sparks some ideas!

Comment: This sounds like a lot of work... also, for slow connections, this could have quite a performance impact.

Comment: It doesn't matter @jbutler483 the websocket delivers all messages for the rooms you're in ...

Comment: Problem: You need to go outside more.

Comment: @jbutler483 the current multi-room experience shows the latest chat message in each room already... just in a tiny area. This is just a layout change. Most likely, the exact same data would continue to be sent (ok, maybe stars would need to be added).